# SQL Server View with TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that is driving me absolutely crazy..

Table `AlarmMsg` looks like this:

```
[TypeID] [smallint] NULL,
[SEFNum] [int] NULL,
[ServerName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[DBName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[PointName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[AppName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Priority] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Value] [float] NOT NULL,
[Limit] [float] NOT NULL,
[Msg] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[DateStamp] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[UID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
```

On top of that `AlarmMsg` table is a view applied looking like this:

```
CREATE VIEW AlarmMsgView 
AS
SELECT     TOP (2000) WITH TIES 
    SEFNum, ServerName, DBName, 
    PointName, AppName, Description, 
    Priority, Value, Limit, Msg, 
    DateStamp, UID
FROM      dbo.AlarmMsg WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY DateStamp DESC
```

This query straight against the table returns the expected ten (10) rows:

```
SELECT TOP(10) [SEFNum]
FROM [RTIME_Logs].[dbo].[AlarmMsg] 
where [Priority] = 1
```

The same query against the view returns....nothing (!):

```
SELECT TOP(10) [SEFNum]
FROM [RTIME_Logs].[dbo].[AlarmMsgView] 
where [Priority] = 1
```

The table `AlarmMsg` contains some 11M+ rows and has a FT index declared on column `Msg`.

Can someone please tell me what's going on here, I think I'm losing my wits.

Comment: What happens if you remove the where clause from the query against the view?  Are you definitely getting results?

Comment: Do you mean it returns 0 rows or it does not return at all

Comment: If I remove the WHERE clause it does return yes!

Comment: And yes, while issuing the same query against the view, it returns exactly zero (0) rows. Nada.

Comment: I'm guessing that your most recent 2000 rows (by DateStamp) do not have Priority = 1?

Comment: RBarryYoung; Thanks for the hint...but based on the criteria..."give me the most recent 2000 rows with a Priority=1" shouldn't that give me the 2000 most recent rows (or less) that has a priority 1 ...?.....

Comment: No, your outer `WHERE` clauses' criteria are only considered after the views criteria are already taken into account. You've said "give me 10 randomly selected rows from (give me the 2000 most recent rows (or less) of any priority) where the priority is 1"

Answer (score -1):

NOLOCK causes this issue.

Read [this](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx) and [this](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/92888/sql_server_92888.html).

Basically, NOLOCK came from SQL Server 2000 era. It needs to be forgotten. You have upgraded your SQL Server (I hope), so you need to upgrade your queries. Consider switching to [READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms173763.aspx) to read data in "unblocked" manner. Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/02/20/concurrency-series-basics-of-transaction-isolation-levels.aspx) to decide which isolation level is best for your situation

EDIT:
After reading the comments from the author, I think this is the reason:

SQL Server is not doing anything wrong. Treat your view as a subquery of the main query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP(2000) col1, col2 FROM aTable ORDER BY Date1 DESC) WHERE priority = 1.
```

In this case the query in the brackets will be executed first, and the WHERE clause will be applied to the resulting set

Comment: Nope. Have removed the "WITH (NOLOCK)" directive too. No difference. This is something else.

Comment: so, in this case there were no "priority one" alarms within the last 2000 alarms (based on DateStamp). What happens is that the TOP(2000) on the view gets executed first and the set is sorted by the DateStamp column in descending order. Within this set in your case there are no priority one alarms (which is great - no alarms - no worries) just add `ORDER BY DateStamp DESC` to the query from the table itself to get the last date of priority one alarm

Comment: Thanks for your response cha. However, with that filter "Priority = 1" I would expect to get the 2000 latest alarms which HAS priority one (1) in descending order i.e. the most recent one on top. Why is SQL Server making this so difficult? Or is it even to be classified as a bug?

Comment: it is not doing anything difficult. Treat your view as a subquery of the main query, something like this: SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP(2000) col1, col2 FROM aTable ORDER BY Date1 DESC) WHERE priority = 1. In this case the query in the brackets will be executed first, and the WHERE clause will be applied to the resulting set

Comment: Thanks again cha. I will try that. However this does whole thing does not make sense to me. The way any set based query language should / would interprete this is "give me the most recent 2000 rows of what matches my criteria" ....that shouldn't be THAT complicated right? Anyway thanks for your help cha it has been good. Not your fault I don't understand this ;)

Comment: Ok guys c'mon. You seem to be a pretty smart bunch. What I am trying to do is to prevent a million+ rows getting into a Crystal report application thus choking it. How hard can it be to reduce a resultset to the TOP 2000 rows in reference to my filter criteria?!